# Отладка приложения на android wear

Tags: android, отладка, android-wear

Пытаюсь сделать отладку приложения! Делаю вот по [этому](https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/android/articles/android-wear-through-adb) туториалу:

1. режим разработчика включен и на планшете и на часах.
2. на часах пишет что  отладка по Bluetooth разрешена.

проблемы:  установив приложение на планшете(без отладки, просто скинув файл апк на планшет) - на часах оно не устанавливается. При отладке приложение на часах тоже не видать.

При этому у меня не получилось сделать следующие шаги из туториала:

1. Выполнение следующих команд ADB в командной строке:
   adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub
   adb connect localhost:4444. Получил ошибку:

   C:\Users\Kirill\AndroidStudioProjects\EnglishFor>adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub

   C:\Users\Kirill\AndroidStudioProjects\EnglishFor>adb connect localhost:4444
   unable to connect to localhost:4444: cannot connect to localhost:4444: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
2. Включение на смартфоне или планшете возможности отладки носимого устройства, подключённого к нему. Тут мне просто не высвечивалось окно с предложением разрешить отладку. а как включить ее самостоятельно - не могу найти где именно это можно включить!

**UDT**: попробовал создать другой проект сразу из двух модулей (phone &  wear), стандартный который создает Андроид студия по умолчанию, отладка на нем тоже не работает, но его я хотя бы смог закинуть apk файл и установить, мой же проект я не смог установить на часы, возможно потому что я модуль для часов добавлял  отдельно и мог где то что то  не указать!?